# CouchDB with Auth0

Tags: couchdb, ionic2, auth0

Is it possible to use Auth0 with CouchDB or Cloudant? If so, does anyone know a tutorial, code sample or github project for examples?

This question was already asked in the Auth0-Forum (not by me) but with no response: https://auth0.com/forum/t/can-you-use-auth0-with-couchdb-or-cloudant/3127

In my special case i want to connect a Ionic 2 App with Auth0 to a CouchDB instance without a middle (API) layer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [couch_jwt_auth](https://github.com/softapalvelin/couch_jwt_auth) plugin which allows users to authenticate via JWT tokens and hence allows this kind of scenario. There's even an [example project](https://github.com/softapalvelin/getting-started-todo) on how to use it with pouchdb and Auth0, so guess this could be kind of useful for you.

I'm using the same plugin to authenticate users and it works flawlessly. I actually maintain a [fork](https://github.com/dmunch/couch_jwt_auth) of it which allows JWT signature verification with asymmetric keys (RS256) - And yeah once I feel confident enough there'll be a pull request.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This project seems interesting to me. Is it possible to use the couch_jwt_auth plugin with Cloudant?

Comment: Sorry I got no experience with cloudant. I'm not sure though it offers the same plugin API as couchdb or even if it's possible to install plugins at all on your cloudant instance.

Comment: I will accept your answer. To get it running on Cloudant is another topic!

Comment: Just realised I opened a WIP pull request at the very beginning. I'm trying to get it merged, feel free to have a look if you're interested in asymmetric keys: https://github.com/softapalvelin/couch_jwt_auth/pull/4

Comment: Why not use the _users db? That seems like it would be the main benefit of using couch..

Answer (score 1):

Will the user have its own database in couchdb? 
Cause without a server side middleware you won't be able to limit access to only the users data.
If thats the case you could consider using oauth for it.

I am not deep into Auth0 but it seems to support it https://auth0.com/docs/oauth2-examples 
as CouchDB too http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#oauth-authentication

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would prefer a own database per user because on client side i want to use pouchdb.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB 3.1 supports JWT auth out of the box.

The [Couch docs on JWT auth are here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#jwt-authentication).

Basically, update the `[chttpd]` section of the configuration to include the JWT section below. Well, you can delete default and/or cookie, but they're quite useful to keep around:

```
[chttpd]
authentication_handlers = {chttpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, jwt_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}
```

Then add this section, which is mentioned without example in the docs:

```
[jwt_auth]
; List of claims to validate
; As of couch 3.1, can NOT require issuer:
; required_claims = {iss, "http://issuer"} <-- does not work
; I left it blank and it's fine
required_claims =
```

and then add or uncomment this section:

```
[jwt_keys]
; Configure at least one key here if using the JWT auth handler.
; I found I had to inclue the 'kid' claim, even if it is just "_default".
; REMINDER: BASE64 ENCODED!
hmac:_default = aGVsbG8=
hmac:demo = aGVsbG8=
```

That's "hello", base64-encoded.

To get a JWT for this, do something like:

```
// once off...
const secret = 'hello'

// then, in an express-jwt handler somewhere...
const token = sign(data, secret, { subject: user.name, audience, algorithm, keyid: 'demo' });
return res.send({ error: null, token })
```

I found that subject (`sub`), audience (`aud`), algorithm (`alg`) and keyid (`kid`) all had to be included as JWT claims or CouchDB wouldn't accept the auth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/softapalvelin/couch_jwt_auth This plugin allows users to authenticate via JWT Tokens.

Comment: Why not user the couch user db?